# Разбор строки с разделителем-табуляцией + игнорирование текста в угловых скобочках

Tags: регулярные-выражения, vbscript

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть строки такого вида -

```
 108    уп  Упаковка        0</nыЪ>
```

Разделитель - табуляция. Нужно распарсить таким образом, чтобы отбирались и значимые значения полей и пустые, то есть, как в данном случае получилось 5 совпадений. Причем то, что в угловых скобках, попадать не должно. У меня получилось (вернее, не получилось) вот что

```
[0-9а-яА-Яa-zA-Z]+(?!>)|\t
```

Но никак не смог сделать так, чтобы не выбирался блок в угловых скобках. Помогите.

Comment: Приведите точную информацию. Какой есть исходный текст и какой результат хотите получить. Приведите варианты, где отсутствует то, что может отсутствовать. Приведите текст, максимально близкий к тому с которым Вы реально будете работать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

Дана строка:

```
108[\t]уп[\t][\t][\t][\t]УпtакSЁовка[\t][\t]0</nыЪ>
```

То же самое, но в виде таблицы с разделением по символу табуляции [\t]:

```
+---+--+-+-+-+-----------+-+-+
|108|уп|-|-|-|УпtакSЁовка|-|0|
+---+--+-+-+-+-----------+-+-+
```

"-" - это пустое значение.

**Желаемая схема захвата значений:**

```
{108}[\t]{уп}[\t]{-}[\t]{-}[\t]{-}[\t]{УпtакSЁовка}[\t]{-}[\t]{0}</nыЪ>
```

{*} - что мы хотим захватить
[\t] - символ табуляции
"-" - пустое значение

С помощью регулярных выражений нельзя захватить "пустоту".
Чтобы как-то выпутаться из этой ситуации,будем захватывать символ табуляции перед пустым значением.

**Итоговая схема захвата:**

```
{108}[\t]{уп}{[\t]}-{[\t]}-{[\t]}-[\t]{УпtакSЁовка}{[\t]}-[\t]{0}</nыЪ>
```

**Регулярное выражение:**

```
@[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9a-zA-Z]+(?=\t|<)|\t(?=\t)@
```

**Объяснение:**

```
/*
 * [а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9a-zA-Z]+(?=\t|<) - комбинация из русских букв, латинских букв и цифр,
 * после которой есть символ табуляции, или "<"
 *
 * \t(?=\t) - символ табуляции, сразу за которым есть еще один
 */
```

**Результат:**

```
/*
 * 1 : 108
 * 2 : уп
 * 3 : [\t]
 * 4 : [\t]
 * 5 : [\t]
 * 6 : УпtакSЁовка
 * 7 : [\t]
 * 8 : 0
 */
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Это то, что нужно. Точно подошло  - решение задачи.

Comment: Как выясняется, имплементация vbscript НЕ поддерживает lookbehind и нотацию с двумя плюсами, идущими подряд! Кстати, выражение без первого lookbehind работает, как надо, но можно ли переписать без двух плюсов - пока не получается...

Comment: @sunny, я переписал регулярку, чтобы она соответствовала правилам vbscript.

Comment: Спасибо! Подправил сообразно своему набору символов - точное сопадение!

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?<!\<\/)[\w\s]++(?!\>)/g
```

все, кроме того, что находится между "</" & ">", если не ошибаюсь =)

```
/(?<!\<\/)[^\<^\>]++(?!\>)/g
```

либо это, оно охватит ещё более широкий диапазон символов.